# Which sources deal with someone who said “bayom Chag haSukkos Hazeh” in “Yaaleh veyovo” in Grace after Meals on Shemini Atzeres

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, mistakes, bentching, shmini-atzeres

In Grace after Meals on Shemini Atzeres, someone said “bayom Chag haSukkos Hazeh” instead of “bayom Shemini Chag Hoatzeres Hazeh” in “Yaaleh veyovo”. My LOR told me that a man has to go back whereas a woman does not, since she has no obligation to eat a meal on Yom Tov.

What sources did he rely on?

Answer (score 4):

[Ma'amar Mordechai 668:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15229&st=&pgnum=318) writes regarding *tefillah* that if one mentions *sukkot* instead of *shemini atzeret* he has not fulfilled his obligation. Although he does not explicitly say the same regarding *birkat hamazon*, he does write further on that:

> צריך שיאמר את יום שמיני חג העצרת הזה בתפילה ובבהמ"ז ... ומשמע דעיכובא הוא
>
> He needs to say "*et yom shemini chag ha'atzeret hazeh*" in *tefillah* and in *birkat hamazon* ... and the implication is that doing otherwise prevents one from fulfilling the obligation.

Regarding a difference between men and women, R. Akiva Eger in [Teshuvah 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1161&st=&pgnum=6&hilite=) makes this distinction in general with regard to forgetting *ya'aleh v'yavo* on *yom tov*.

He writes that women do not repeat *birkat hamazon* on *yom tov* if they forget *ya'aleh v'yavo*, as they are not obligated to eat like men are, since *oneg yom tov* is a time-bound positive *mitzvah*.

---

Note that this *pesak* is not necessarily agreed to by all. For example, R. E. Melamed in a footnote [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/13-07-01/) writes that no-one should repeat *birkat hamzaon* if they made this mistake, as it there is a 'double doubt' ([some](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam.28.15?lang=bi) [say](https://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.668.1?lang=bi) that *chag hasukkot* is okay instead of *shemini chag ha'atzeret* after the fact, and [some say](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.188.24.1?lang=bi)  neither men nor women repeat *birkat hamazon* if they forget *ya'aleh v'yavo* on *yom tov*, as no-one has an obligation to eat bread then (apart from the first nights of *pesach* and *sukkot*)).